# Visited website on different dates - apa style

Tags: citations, citation-style

Ray, B. (2018, June 25). NB-IoT vs. LoRa vs. Sigfox. Retrieved January 4, 2019, from https://www.link-labs.com/blog/nb-iot-vs-lora-vs-sigfox

In the source reference of my paper I refer to a website. I consulted this website for example on various dates. Do I only have to write the last date or each date separately?

Comment: Has the information you retrieved changed?

Comment: @henning How would the OP know? Changes can be very subtle.

Comment: @user2768 I suppose OP references the website for a specific information. Whether the information is still on the website should be easy to verify.

Comment: See https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/6074/22768

Answer (score 3):

From the link you provided I don't think you need to include the retrieval date for the following reasons.

The blog post you link has a publication date.

A blog post in the [APA Blog](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/website/) states the following about website dates.

> **Determining Website Dates**
>
> A second source of confusion is that many websites or webpages do not include publication dates. If no date of publication is provided, use the letters n.d. (which stand for “no date”). The copyright date on the website itself should not be used as the publication date for particular content on that site.
>
> If multiple dates are provided, use the most recent date on which the content was changed. For example, if the site says the content was first published in 2010 and last updated on August 6, 2016, then use the date 2016 in the in-text citation and reference list. However, if the site says it was first published in 2010 and last reviewed in July 2016, then use the date 2010 because a review does not imply that any information was changed.

The following 2 guides also indicate to use a retrieval date if info on page is likely to change over time.

From [APA Style Website](https://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/when-include-retrieval-date)

> When a DOI is not available, and a URL is included, do not include retrieval dates unless the source material may change over time (e.g., wikis).

From [APA 6th Edition - University of Lincoln guide](https://guides.library.lincoln.ac.uk/c.php?g=110736&p=717960)

> When citing sources that you find on the Internet you only need to include a retrieval date if the information you viewed is likely to change over time.  If you reference an article from a wiki, for example, you would want to include a retrieval date because information in a wiki can be subject to a lot of change.

Comment: Given that researchers have no assurance as to whether material may change, surely a retrieval date should be included?

Comment: @user2768 I would be inclined to agree, but the APA style guide doesn't seem to promote that course.

Comment: I wonder whether the guide failed to consider that particular case. Regardless, the author will be blamed, rather than the guide, if any issue arises. So, I'd recommend erring on the side of caution and assuming all content might change. I'm tempted to suggest that some sources (e.g., the NYT) could be excluded when they include notes on revisions, but that isn't the most cautious.

Comment: @user2768 both MLA and Chicago also do not require retrieval dates. The requirement for a retrieval date was dropped from APA 5 to APA 6: http://owll.massey.ac.nz/referencing/apa-5th-vs-6th-edition.php#retrieval-date

Comment: @StrongBad I posit that numerous sources will change - simply because websites disappear (e.g., due to bankruptcy), administrators change URL structures, ... - hence, the retrieval date is typically needed, unless the author knows (which they cannot possibly) that the source will never change. (I haven't even touched upon the possibility of content changing.)

Comment: @user2768 posit what you want, but the 3 major style guides do not require retrieval dates. Both MLA and APA explicitly dropped the requirement over time. I think that is pretty good evidence that the people who know about these things do not think the retrieval date is needed. See my answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/6074/929

Comment: @StrongBad It isn't true that "3 major style guides do not require retrieval dates," MLA and APA only make such a requirement on a vaguely worded basis, namely, for "a reliable, stable source" and when "the source is [un]likely to change often." I claim no source is stable and there's plenty of evidence to support that. E.g., https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/51865/what-percentage-of-links-posted-in-published-articles-are-dead

Comment: *then use the date 2010 because a review does not imply that any information was changed.* This is odd ... it doesn't *imply* that, but it doesn't imply that it *hasn't*.